# How to use mutation's function in the getter's method in vuex store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

```
export const state = () => ({ 
   results: []
})

export const mutations = { 
   initialFilters(state, res) {
      // write something .....
   }
}
```

> **initialFilters()** function does'nt recognize in mutations method

```
export const getters = {
   filter(state, mutations) {
     let results = mutations.initialFilters(state.results);
     return results;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getters and Computed functions Shouldn't have side-effects like calling mutations.